# php date does not posted in the db table

Tags: php, mysql, variables, datetime

Hi im trying to hard code and set a date to a variable inorder to insert it in db table, but after all my efforts it always prints 0000-00-00 00:00:00. data type in the date column of the table is just datetime

following is the code i tried

```
$retval      = '2007-04-19 12:50:00';
$str_cols = "gmid, panelID, trackerID, timestamp";
$str_values ="$gmid, $panel_id, $track, $retval";
$table = "tracktable_".$track;
$query = "INSERT INTO $table ($str_cols) VALUES ($str_values)";
```

can any body help on this to get the assigned date in the db table

Comment: What is `$retval`, and why is that going into the database as your date/time? Also quoting is important. `$str_values ="$gmid, $panel_id, $track, '$time'";`

Comment: sorry some part is missing ill edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$str_cols = "gmid, panelID, trackerID, `timestamp`";
$str_values ="$gmid, $panel_id, $track, '$retval'";
```

Answer (score 2):

timestamp is a keyword so it should be in apostrophe like '`timestamp`'.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`gmid`, `panelID`, `trackerID`, `timestamp') VALUES ('".$gmid."', '".$panel_id."', '".$track."', '".$retval."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

For it to function surely. Add backticks to your `$table`. Also there is no single quotes in your values. Use this for sure it will work.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `$table` (gmid, panelID, trackerID, timestamp) VALUES ('$gmid', '$panel_id', '$track', '$retval')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`gmid`, `panelID`, `trackerID`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('".$gmid."', '".$panel_id."', '".$track."', '".$retval."')";
```